# Powershell Try Catch Continue

Tags: loops, powershell, try-catch

I have a working powershell script, but when it cannot find a hostname, it throws a non-terminating exception and writes to the screen that that hostname was unable to be found.  I want to catch that exception and simply write to the screen: Not Found.  Then I want the script to carry on like normal.

Here is the script:

```
$listOfComputers = IMPORT-CSV test.txt
$b = "2013-09-11"
ForEach($computer in $listOfComputers){
$name = $computer.Name
Write-Host $name -NoNewLine
try{$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $name)}
catch [Exception] {write-host "  Not Found" -foreground blue}
$key = $reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\WindowsUpdate\\Auto Update\\Results\\Install")
$a = $key.GetValue("LastSuccessTime")
$a = $a.Substring(0,10)
if($a -le $b){Write-Host " " $a -foreground magenta}
else{Write-Host " " $a} 
}
```

Here is the output:

> ```
> PS C:\PowerShell Scripts> .\windowsUpdates.ps1
> OLDBEAR  Not Found
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
> At C:\PowerShell Scripts\windowsUpdates.ps1:8 char:1
> + $key =
> $reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\WindowsUpd
> ```
>
> ...
>       + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       ~~~
>           + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
>
> ```
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
> At C:\PowerShell Scripts\windowsUpdates.ps1:9 char:1
> + $a = $key.GetValue("LastSuccessTime")
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
>
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
> At C:\PowerShell Scripts\windowsUpdates.ps1:10 char:1
> + $a = $a.Substring(0,10)
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
> ```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Try/catch does not seem to have an effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142211/try-catch-does-not-seem-to-have-an-effect). The answers regarding `ErrorActionPreference` will help you. You can set the preference for your whole script, or per-cmdlet.

Comment: I have already tried setting ErrorActionPreference.  No use to me, unless I can print to the screen each time that the error happens.  With ErrorActionPreference, I was unable to do that.

Comment: ...so you did something like `try { get-content "Herp" -ErrorAction stop } catch { "Derp" }` and that did not give your desired behavior? Because it absolutely should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip the try/catch altogether, and instead test for connectivity *before* attempting to access the registry. This should speed your script up, as you won't be waiting for a timeout from `OpenRemoteBaseKey` on systems that are offline.

```
$listOfComputers = IMPORT-CSV test.txt
$b = "2013-09-11"
ForEach($computer in $listOfComputers){
    $name = $computer.Name
    Write-Host $name -NoNewLine
    if (-not (Test-Connection -computername $name -count 1 -Quiet -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        write-host "  Not Found" -foreground blue;
        continue;
    }
    $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $name)

    $key = $reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\WindowsUpdate\\Auto Update\\Results\\Install")
    $a = $key.GetValue("LastSuccessTime")
    $a = $a.Substring(0,10)
    if($a -le $b) {
        Write-Host " " $a -foreground magenta
    }
    else {
        Write-Host " " $a;
    } 
}
```

You could also test connectivity in bulk before hitting the main loop, filtering any computers that aren't accessible out of your list. See my answer [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19938621/1324345) for a way to do that.